# Can I ask aspell to search multiple paths for dictionary files?

Tags: aspell

I've managed to get custom dictionaries working with aspell by creating a `.multi` file which adds my custom `.rws` file on top of my base language. In my case en-GB.

My "foo" variant is in a separate part of the file system at `/my/custom/en_GB-foo.multi`, and looks like this:

```
add foo.rws
add /usr/lib64/aspell-0.60/en_GB.multi
```

It works, but the absolute path is inconvenient. I'd prefer it looked like this:

```
add foo.rws
add en_GB.multi
```

My current best workaround is a symlink: e.g. `/my/custom/base => /usr/lib64/aspell-0.60`, so I can do this:

```
add foo.rws
add base/en_GB.multi
```

It works as expected, when I invoke aspell like this:

```
aspell --lang=en_GB --variety=foo --dict-dir=/my/custom check file.txt
```

For whatever reason, when aspell follows the path to the base language, all relative paths from then on are resolved according to their installed location, despite my custom `dict-dir` setting. This is all good!

BUT - Is there a "proper" way to have aspell search two paths for dictionary files? I've tried `local-data-dir`, but I clearly misunderstand what this is for. I've tried specifying `dict-dir` multiple times, and with multiple values. I've tried placing my custom files in `home-dir`. None of this has worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Is there a "proper" way to have `aspell` search two paths for dictionary files?

You can use the `--extra-dicts` option:

```
--add-extra-dicts dict1 --add-extra-dicts dict2
```

Source: [adding many dictionaries to aspell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53992811)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For completeness, the command can reference the `.rws` file directly, with no need for the `.multi` file. Also no need for the `--add-` prefix  if only adding one custom dictionary on top of base language. In my case: `aspell --lang=en_GB --extra-dicts=/my/custom/foo.rws check ...`